# Can I use javascript timer in a mobile browser

Tags: javascript, mobile, timer

I am using IE in a mobile browser.  I add a javascript function to a button that when the User clicks it says 'hello'.

This works.

I then add a timer.

On a desktop browser it works.

it does not work on my mobile browser.

This is my code.  (note I Had just tried placing an alert('hi'); in the swapImages() and that did not work either.

```
 var div = document.getElementById('divImage');
        var imgCached = document.getElementById('imgCached');

        document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true);

        function OnImgLoaded() {
          img1.src = imgCached.src;
        }

        var interval = 30;
        var _timer;
        var _index = 0;

        function test() {
            _timer = setInterval('swapImages()', interval);
        }

        function swapImages() {
            imgCached.onload = OnImgLoaded();
            imgCached.src = 'my server url~/' + '0000' + _index + '.jpg';
            _index = _index + 1;
            if (_index == 10) {
                _index = 0;
                clearTimeout(_timer);
            }
    }
```

UPDATE!!
I had been runningit on Chrome desktop and not IE. I am mow testing it in IE desktop. I get the same erro so now I can debug.

The error is this line:
img1.src = imgCached.src;

It tells me:
Unable to get property 'src' of undefined or null reference

I have changed the code to:
var imgLive = document.getElementById('imgLive'); (I have renamed the img control)

```
function OnImgLoaded() {
imgLive.src = imgCached.src;
}
```

I get the same error.

I look in Source and the control is correctly named..

Thanks

Comment: perhaps post some code? setTimeout definitely works on mobile.

Comment: @BenClayton Hi Ben, I did not think it work submitting code because it was so simple and the fact that it works on desktop browser.  I will amend my original question.. thanks

Comment: Please post some code so that we can see what you are trying to do. What version of IE for mobile are you using?

Comment: @tmadsen Hi, thanks for taking a look.  I am using IE and the version is I think IE4

Comment: setInterval is available in IE4 according to this source: http://books.google.dk/books?id=oPu0jczoxscC&pg=PA880&lpg=PA880&dq=IE4+setinterval+compatability&source=bl&ots=ilz2OgDGEH&sig=ValpI5N2EHe3oj3U8eZMePugwV8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=frtfUoYktK_hBKDvgYgC&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=IE4%20setinterval%20compatability&f=false

Comment: I am using Windows Mobile 6.5 (yes I know :). I dod not know if that will affect things here.

Comment: I am going to repost this to make things clearer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not sure that the following line is valid in your mobile phone:

```
imgCached.src = 'http://127.0.0.1/Cloud/test/' ...
```

the timer executes successfully, but the image doesn't get the proper src since the device **doesn't run a web server** on it (unless you configured one).

and to answer your topic question, yes- you can use javascript timers in mobile browsers just like desktop browsers.

hope that helped.

Comment: Hi, you are quite right I did have the wrong URL in (I am not normally that thick). But, it still did not work.

Comment: try putting an `alert('test')` inside the timer just to see if the timer is working

Comment: Hi, I had did that but it did not work. Interestingly though I tested it in Opera Mobile and it DID work..

Comment: is there any way for you to debug the mobile IE and see if there are any javascript errors ?

Comment: Hi,I was trying to find a way to do that before but could not see how to - hence why I came here :)

Comment: try to run it in IE without this line:         `document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true);`

Comment: is all your js code wrapped with `window.onload = function() { // code }` ?

Comment: try it, i'm shooting in the dark just like you, because i don't have a device with IE browser on it ;-)

Comment: unfortunately no effect - but thaks for the suggestion

Comment: another thing, you'r setting `setInterval` and using `clearTimeout`, you should use `clearInterval`. anyway i'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am normally a server side person.  I have recently been converted to javascript + jquery. After this is solved i was going to ask about ajax/jquery calls.. :)

Comment: Hi, I just realised i had been trying it on Chrome in my desktop. If I run it in IE desktop I get the same issues. DOH! At least I can debug it now. I will update my question

Comment: Hi, I changed it to imgLive. I thought I had amended the question. This question has now become messy - all my fault.

Comment: change `imgCached.onload = OnImgLoaded();` to `imgCached.onload = OnImgLoaded;`

Comment: I moved the javascript to the bottom of the page. The control is recognised now.  Now the desktop works but the mobile version doesnt'  this is why I was a server developer..

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Do you ever call the `test` function, that starts the timer?

Second: Maybe it's really `document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true)`, that fails - it may not be enabled in the mobile version of IE that you are using. You can check if it's enabled using the `queryCommandEnabled` function, see more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536676(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi, good thinking. I disabled the document.exeCommand but this did not work.  I made sure i was properly calling the test function by putting an alert box in. The alert popped up but that was it.

Comment: `setInterval('swapImages()', interval)` ought to work according to the documentation I could find (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536749(v=vs.85).aspx). Have you tried other alternatives, like `setInterval(swapImages, interval)`, or `setInterval(function() {swapImages()}, interval)`?

Comment: hi, If I change  _timer = setInterval('swapImages()', interval); to _timer = setInterval(swapImages(), interval) It will fire once but only once...

Comment: Did you try `setInterval(swapImages, interval)` (no parentheses), like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536749(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi, I just realised i had been trying it on Chrome in my desktop. If I run it in IE desktop I get the same issues. DOH! At least I can debug it now. I will update my question